# Python Apache spark connect to redshift

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

i am following this url here to connect pyspark to redshift :

[Spark Redshift with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307640/spark-redshift-with-python)

I created a folder, downloaded the

RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.12.1017.jar
and created the Python file sample.py with the below code

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
aws_access_key = "xxxx"
aws_secret_key = "xxxxyyyy"
bucket = "redshiftbucketadrian"
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").appName("Connect to redshift").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sql_context =    HiveContext(sc)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", aws_access_key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", aws_secret_key)
df = sql_context.read\
    .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")\
    .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://xxxxx")\
    .option("dbtable", "dev")\
    .option("tempdir", "s3n://xxxx/")\
    .load()
```

I then executed the command below:

```
spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.10:0.5.0 --jars RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.12.1017.jar sample.py
```

However, it keeps showing me this

[image]

```
.0:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixed
Sleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-04-04 21:27:35 INFO  Client:871 - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0
.0:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixed
Sleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-04-04 21:27:37 INFO  Client:871 - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0
.0:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixed
Sleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-04-04 21:27:39 INFO  Client:871 - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0
.0:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixed
Sleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

What am i missing?

Comment: you sure you have the right host?

Comment: Hi yes host is correct.